# Count entities by date that fall between start date and end date (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, date, time

Using Postgres, I'm trying to get a count of active entities by day over the past year.

For each entity I have a name, a start date, an end date. Assume the schema below-

Table x

```
Entity|Start_date|End_date
x | 2018-01-07  |2018-01-23
y | 2018-01-08  |2018-04-01
z | 2018-01-22  |2018-01-24
```

What I'm trying to output

```
Date|Count
2018-01-01|0
...
2018-01-07|1
...
2018-01-22|3
2018-01-23|3
2018-01-24|2
2018-01-25|1
...
2018-08-15|0
```

Have created a date table but don't know what to join it on. Feel like I have to create another table, then aggregate it but not sure what it is. If I don't need to create an additional table then great.

Any help would be appreciated! T

*edit - FWIW I've researched but I'm not quite sure what it is I need to research here - what function or join I'm missing*

*edit 2 - to include example*

Comment: Please share schema of your tables and an example what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why have you created a date table? Assuming these entities are already in a table with the aforementioned fields, a query can get you the result you want - but as requested above, you need to provide some more info.

Comment: Example schema and example of what I'm trying to achieve attached @SookieSingh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a left joining year's dates and entities like:

```
select t.d, count(e.entity)  
from generate_series(
   make_date(date_part('year',current_date)::integer,1,1), 
   make_date(date_part('year',current_date)::integer,12,31), 
   '1 day'::interval) t(d)
left join entities e 
   on t.d between e.start_date and e.end_date
group by t.d
order by t.d;
```

Comment: thank you! Made a couple of adaptions around the generate series (worked off a pre-built date table for efficiencies sake) but the between join is exactly what I was missing. Thanks for saving me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

well, you need count days for every `Start_date` and `End_date` from "x" table. (this happens in `left join` subquery).

Then you need just create all year days list and "left join" those all day to counted days from "x" table.

Hope, this is what you want and if so,  also hope, do you understand, what I tried to explain.

```
WITH year_days as (
    select * from generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2018-12-31'::date, '1 day'::interval) as d
),
x(Entity, Start_date, End_date) AS (
values 
('x','2018-01-07'::date, '2018-01-23'::date),
('y','2018-01-08'::date, '2018-04-01'::date),
('z','2018-01-22'::date, '2018-01-24'::date)
)

select year_days.d, coalesce(t.cnt, 0) from  year_days
left join (
    select generate_series(Start_date, End_date, '1 day'::interval) as d , count(*) as cnt  from x group by d
 ) t
on year_days.d = t.d
```